# monitor JDBC connections

Tags: tomcat, jdbc, jmx

I am trying to monitor JDBC connections in tomcat using JMX.

But it is giving information only regarding  the Datasource resources, I want the status of connection defined in Database.properties file.

Is there any way to get their status?

Comment: I just  want the number of busy and idle threads not the waiting or block status.

Comment: What is `Database.properties`? How is it related to Tomcat, what framework is this?

Comment: Hi Rupinder, did you finally find such a utility?

Answer (score 5):

With this Servlet 3.0 example you can monitor all information in the  org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx.ConnectionPool including the Idle and Active connections.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.management.MBeanAttributeInfo;
import javax.management.MBeanInfo;
import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.ObjectName;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
@WebServlet("/poolmonitor")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
        writer.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        writer.println("<html>");
        writer.println("<body>");
        writer.println("<p><h1>Tomcat Pool</h1></p><p>");
        try {
            MBeanServer server = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
            Set<ObjectName> objectNames = server.queryNames(null, null);
            for (ObjectName name : objectNames) {
                MBeanInfo info = server.getMBeanInfo(name);
                if (info.getClassName().equals(
                        "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.jmx.ConnectionPool")) {
                    for (MBeanAttributeInfo mf : info.getAttributes()) {
                        Object attributeValue = server.getAttribute(name,
                                mf.getName());
                        if (attributeValue != null) {
                            writer.println("" + mf.getName() + " : "
                                    + attributeValue.toString() + "<br/>");

                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        writer.println("</p></body>");
        writer.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You are asking for more than JNDI DataSource information (such as busy and idle threads).

I highly recommend this resource for JMX-based monitoring:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/Monitoring